# Error on: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Order Qty"}

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm having error on my code wherein im finding a text but it does not display based on the string I have on my excel. I assume that it is due to frame set up.

here is my code:

```
'if (driver.findElement(By.linkText(reports)).isDisplayed())
 {

  System.out.println("report = "+ reports + "does not exist");

  }
else
  {

  System.out.println("report = "+ reports + "does not exist");

  }

 }
```

Take note that report = **"Order Qty"** (text is extracted on excel)

here is the element that I need to find on browser [image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the element by linkText try finding the elements by text using XPath.

Since you are using the `isDisplayed()` method to check if the element is visible or not, I'm assuming you are expecting the element to be sometime not visible. In this case, if the element is not visible it will always throw the NoSuchElement exception.
To avoid this, either you have to use the condition inside a try block and handle the exception in the catch block. Or you can use `findElements` and check the list size which will never throw the exception.

As mentioned by cruisepandey, you should also use explicit waits for element loading delays.

```java
String reports = "Order Qty";
List<WebElement> list = new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='kpi-report-wrapper']/h2[contains('"+reports+"')]")));

if(list.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("report = "+reports+ "does not exist" );
}else {
    System.out.println("report = "+reports+ "exists");
}
```

Comment: hello last time this code is working for me, but now the element is not visible. and now its not working. :(

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Xpath :

```
//h2[text()='Order Qty']
```

Just make sure this shouldn't be in any frame.

However, introducing WebDriverWait will be great idea for stability.

for WebDriverWait :

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable (By.xpath("//h2[text()='Order Qty']")));
```

This would return you a web element.